# How do I configure JNBridge library on Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, jnbridge

We have an ASP.Net Web Forms application that consumes a Java library project using JNBridge Pro, this has been working really well on-premises.
The company has decided to embrace Azure and moving most of the Web apps to Azure Web Apps which is a good move.
However, when trying to migrate this project which uses JNBridge I haven't been successful so far in configuring the JNBridge Library.
I have tried various things but I end up with the following error

```
*System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectWrapper' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.JavaSides' threw an exception. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: No such interface supported
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Initialize()
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()
   at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.proxym.RLMProductionLicenseManager.isHyperVHost()
   at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.proxym.RLMProductionLicenseManager.isOnVM()
   at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.proxym.RLMProductionLicenseManager.initializeAndLoadLicense(String licenseLocation)
   at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.proxym.RLMProductionLicenseManager.loadLicense()
   at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.proxym.ProxyMFactory.getInstance(String lmType)
   at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.JavaSides..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at com.jnbridge.jnbproxy.JavaSides.getInitialEntry()
   at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectHelper..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectWrapper..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at com.jnbridge.jnbcore.ObjectWrapper..ctor()
   at java.lang.Object..ctor()
   at com.xantura.api.admin.EventMonitor..ctor()*
```

I am new to Azure Web App, so I am guessing I must be doing something silly, I have checked the dotNetToJavaConfig section and all the paths associated with that section, they all seem good.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Copying the standard binaries did not work.

I managed to resolve this issue with help from the JNBridge support team, they provided me with a patch to work around a .NET API that was not supported on Azure. You need to obtain this patch from JNBridge to resolve this issue.

One can contact the support team at JNBridge for more information. They were very helpful in resolving this issue.